# Flutter Android gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-android, android-studio-bumblebee

I have already update the latest Android Gradle version but still showing the error when generating the signed bundle.

**generating signed bundle requires you to update the android gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher**

[image]

Below i have share the version details.

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
}
```

}

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
```

Android studio version

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675, built on March 16, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart (211.7817), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.21-release-334-AS7442.40), io.flutter (66.0.1)

Flutter version

Flutter 2.10.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5f105a6ca7 (3 months ago) • 2022-02-01 14:15:42 -0800
Engine • revision 776efd2034
Tools • Dart 2.16.0 • DevTools 2.9.2

Comment: change your kotlin version to ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' or one matches with your configuration

Comment: @OsamaBuzdar I have changed the kotlin version "1.6.21" to 1.6.10 but still getting the same error.

Comment: Use the command line to create an app bundle https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution? I've just opened a ticket at Jetbrains to see what they say.

Comment: Yes @valley , I have found the solution. you need to open android project like this from your flutter project. 
https://prnt.sc/o5BnsZ51FfZ4

Comment: Oh my, it's so strange having to open AS for being able to create such a build... But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Is it working or not for you @valley?

Comment: Actually yes, but i use the CLI now to create the build.

Answer (score 0):

**Change Your Build Gradle File Like Below**

I think you are not in the latest version yet.

I Used this command to upgrade most the latest version

```
flutter channel dev
```

Now you can change your Build Gradle(Android Level)

```
   buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}
```

- 

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```